# first tcp echo client cant communicate with second tcp echo client(Bad file descriptor)

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, network-programming

My application is Multiuser Echo chat program. If a client sends message the server sends to all clients including the client from which the message originates. It is implemented in c.

server forked a process for each new client connection.
all child processes can access socket descriptor of all clients which are stored in shared memory

when there is one client the message is echoed back correctly. When second client is joined
and sends message it echoes back to two clients correctly.

When first client send message it is transmited back to first client correctly .But when tried to send that message to second client it failed with error *Bad file descriptor*

similarly every client can transmit message to clients connected before and to itself, but cant to clients connected later

how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Accessing a socket descriptor doesn't mean you can access the socket. You would need to share the sockets themselves, not their descriptors.

Also, the results of two processes trying to send on the same TCP connection at the same time are undefined. The data might be interleaved, for example.

So your design is basically broken.

You could actually share the sockets. How you do that is platform-dependent. You would also need to use some form of IPC to arbitrate which process can write to the socket. You could use a semaphore for each socket, for example.

Comment: i shared the sockaddr_in variable get from second argument of accept().But we need file descriptor to send().

Comment: @Sankaran: The `sockaddr_in` variable is the *address* of the socket. By sharing it, you just told other processes what the address of your socket is. That certainly doesn't share the socket itself.